# Update pc when pc is powered off

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've looked to my Windows 10 Updates where I read this:

> Reboot is scheduled when you usually are not utilizing the device (currently it would be tomorrow at 03:30 AM).
>
> <sup>(Translated from Dutch to English)</sup>

But I think this is impossible, because when you don't use your Windows 10 PC (certainly not at 03:30 AM), he can't update, what is normal of course. But why says Microsoft this? Didn't she know that this is not possible?

Comment: It will turn itself on to install the updates (provided there is power available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand this, `the reboot is scheduled` for that time.  Much of the updating process may occur at another time.  However, the reboot will happen at 3:30pm, if the computer is not being used.

If the computer is being used, then the person who uses the computer probably does not want the computer to reboot while the computer is actively being used.  Hopefully that person will reboot when that person is done using the computer.

Have people log off the computer when they are not using the computer.  This good habit allows the update process to know that nobody is actively using the computer, so automated rebooting is likely to be safe at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer will apply the updates at this time if connected, otherwise it will be in the next boot. Simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you turn off the machine, it will begin the updates then. If you do not turn off the machine, it will turn reboot itself at 3.30am to install the queued updates.

It is impossible for it to update without power, of course.